# Error reading with Json (CoinWarz)

Tags: jquery, json

I'm very very new reading data wiht JQuery but I have done already some little projects. I have always read Json data the same way but with this link coinwarz it doesnt work. Anyone knows what is the dump error? Thanks.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
 dataType: "json",
 url: "https://www.coinwarz.com/v1/api/coininformation/?apikey=XXXX&cointag=BTC",
 success: function( data ) {
console.log("Hi");
   for ( var member in data) {

     // Change the abbreviation to be the currancy you want
        var value = data[member]
        console.log(value);

     }
   }
});
```

Comment: The ; missing isnt the answer

Comment: It's not a good idea to expose your `apikey` to the world, but also it looks like your limit on daily request has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to read is data.Data which is the data you actually want to loop through, I am not sure what you are trying to do with these data but I advise having a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp) and maybe filter would be useful for checking the currency you want  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),
and maybe you want to add one condition first which is `if(data.success === true)` before actually reading the data

what I would do is

```
    success: function( data ) {
    console.log("Hi");
// if the status is ok 
if(data.Success == true){
  /// Filter function will loop through your data list and return the list containing the data meeting the condition, in this case exchange equal to the currency you want.      
  var theoneIwant = data.Data.filter(function(currency){
  return currency.Exchange === "the currancy you want";
});
}
}
// success is false, show error 
else {console.log("Error " + data.Message);}
```